# T-SQL Merging two COUNT and GROUP BY queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following 2 queries that I have written:

```
SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name' ,COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Closed', CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'Date Closed' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name
ORDER BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) DESC
```

AND

```
SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name', COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Open', CAST(t.Created AS DATE) As 'Date Open' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE), g.Name
ORDER BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE) DESC
```

Both of which are doing what I want, they each result with the following layout:

```
| Group Name | Tickets Open | Date Open |
-----------------------------------------
| Foo        | 13           | 2016-01-02|
| Bar        | 9            | 2016-01-02|
| Foo        | 70           | 2016-01-01|
| Bar        | 34           | 2016-01-01|
```

The query to fetch closed tickets is obviously the same layout, just different numbers (group names are still the same), I've been trying to merge the 2 queries to return the data in the following layout:

```
| Group Name | Tickets Open | Tickets Closed | Date      |
----------------------------------------------------------
| Foo        | 13           | 5              | 2016-01-02|
| Bar        | 9            | 8              | 2016-01-02|
| Foo        | 70           | 15             | 2016-01-01|
| Bar        | 34           | 12             | 2016-01-01|
```

I've tried using the UNION keyword, but I can't get it to work with GROUP BY keyword, I keep getting error regarding columns not being contained in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.

If someone knows how to return the data in the above format, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Both query are grouping by different date. You want to equate both date ?

Comment: If I understand you want for each group name, on each date, the number of Tickets Open and the Number of Tickets Closed.  Is that accurate?

Comment: you could make both the queries into sub queries, then join them with a FULL OUTER JOIN on 'group name' and 'date',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use CTEs for each and then join on group and date. I used a full join so you won't exclude rows that only have open or only have closed.

Additionally, UNION combines sets vertically not horizontally in so much that if you have two sets of data with the same format a UNION will be the combination of all the rows of each. You'd maintain the same 3 column format and just have all the rows in one larger set, but I don't think that is what you are after judging by your example.

```
WITH OPENCTE AS
(
    SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name', COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Open', CAST(t.Created AS DATE) As 'Date Open' FROM Tickets t
    JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
    GROUP BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE), g.Name
)
, CLOSECTE AS
(
SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name' ,COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Closed', CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'Date Closed' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name
)
SELECT 'Group Name'
    ,'Tickets Open'
    ,'Tickets Closed'
    ,'Date Closed'
FROM OPENCTE AS O
    FULL JOIN CLOSECTE AS C
        ON O.[Group Name] = C.[Group Name]
            AND O.[Date Open] = C.[Date Closed]
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, I ended up using this query first and it worked fine. Also learnt about Common Table Expressions which was also a big bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I see dates closed are same for both open and close..This query is built  under assumption that there will be an entry for each day in both tickets close and open..If that is the case,you can do a join like below else you can do a full join

```
;with(opentickets)
as
(
SELECT g.Name As 'GroupName', COUNT(*) As 'TicketsOpen', CAST(t.Created AS DATE) As 'DateOpen' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE), g.Name
)
,closedtickets
as
(
SELECT g.Name As 'GroupName' ,COUNT(*) As 'TicketsClosed', CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'DateClosed' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name
)
select 
c.GroupName,c.ticketsopen as ticketsopen,c.TicketsClosed as ticketsclosed,c.dateclosed
 from
opentickets o
 join
closedtickets c
on c.GroupName=o.GroupName
and o.dateopen=c.dateclosed
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to put both query's in CTE and then JOIN them:

```
;WITH [Open] AS (
    SELECT  g.Name As 'Group Name' ,
            COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Closed', 
            CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'Date Closed',
            CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) as [oDate]
    FROM Tickets t
    JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
    GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name
), [Close] AS (
    SELECT  g.Name As 'Group Name', 
            COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Open', 
            CAST(t.Created AS DATE) As 'Date Open'
    FROM Tickets t
    JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
    GROUP BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE), g.Name
)

SELECT *
FROM [Open] o
LEFT JOIN [Close] c
    ON c.[Group Name] = o.[Group Name] 
ORDER BY [oDate] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your games started and ended at the same date:

```
SELECT c.Group_Name, o.Tickets_Open, c.Tickets_Closed, c.Game_Date
FROM (
SELECT g.Name As Group_Name ,COUNT(*) As Tickets_Closed, CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As Game_Date FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name) AS C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT g.Name As Group_Name, COUNT(*) As Tickets_Open, CAST(t.Created AS DATE) As Game_Date FROM Tickets t
    JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
    GROUP BY CAST(t.Created AS DATE), g.Name
) as o ON c.Group_Name = o.Group_Name and c.Game_Date = o.Game_Date
ORDER BY o.Tickets_Open, c.Tickets_Closed, c.Group_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(Q1.[group name],Q2.[group name]) AS [date], Q2.[tickets open], Q1.[tickets closed], COALESCE(Q1.TheDate,Q2.TheDate) as [date] FROM
(SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name' ,COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Closed', CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'TheDate' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name) Q1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT g.Name As 'Group Name' ,COUNT(*) As 'Tickets Closed', CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE) As 'TheDate' FROM Tickets t
JOIN Groups g ON g.ID = t.AssignedGroup
GROUP BY CAST(t.ResolvedAt AS DATE), g.Name) Q2 
ON Q1.[group name] = Q2.[group name] AND Q1.TheDate = Q2.Thedate
```